# Why need to click twice to update the state? (React.js, React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to create Update Form Modal for edit the original data. My code actually works, but there is a bug which requires the button to be double-clicked to display data from API (getTeamsById()).

The Button

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn"
  onClick={() => handleUpdateTeams(team.id)}
>
  <img
    src="/img/icon/ic_edit.png"
    alt="edit"
    className="container-img"
  />
</button>
```

handleUpdateTeams()

```
  const handleUpdateTeams = (teamId) => {
    dispatch(getTeamsById(teamId))
      .then(() => {
        setId(teamId);
        let data = myTeam.userData;
        setPhone(data.user.phone);
        setEmail(data.user.email);
        setFullName(data.user.fullName);
        setDateOfBirth(moment(data.user.birthday).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        setGender(data.user.gender);
        setDescription(data.description);
        setSpecialist(data.specialist);
        setKTPNumber(data.KTPNumber);
        setSIPNumber(data.SIPNumber);
        setSTRNumber(data.STRNumber);
        setWorkingExperience(data.workExperience);
        setServiceFee(data.serviceFee);
        setAvatar(data.user.avatar);
        setKtp(data.KTPFile);
        setSip(data.SIPFile);
        setStr(data.STRFile);
      })
      .then(setUpdateTeamsModal(true));
  };
```

The Modal

```
  const renderUpdateTeams = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        modalTitle="Update Healthcare Professional"
        show={updateTeamsModal}
        size="lg"
        handleClose={() => handleCloseModal()}
        buttons={[
          {
            label: "Update",
            color: "warning",
            onClick: actionUpdateTeams,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Row>
          <Col md>
            <Input
              name="avatar"
              label="Profile Picture"
              type="file"
              accept="image/*"
              onChange={handleProfilePicture}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col md>
            <Input
              label="Full Name"
              placeholder="Input Full Name"
              type="text"
              value={fullName}
              onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>

    .....

    <Row>
          <Col md>
            <Input
              label="Service Fee"
              placeholder="Input Service Fee"
              type="number"
              min="0"
              value={serviceFee}
              onChange={(e) => setServiceFee(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Modal>
    );
  };
```

Do you have any solution for this problem/bug?, all suggestions will be very helpful. By the way I am using react-redux for state management.

Comment: Can you provide a MRE, it's hard to tell anything with the given implementation.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu sorry for my bad explanation, the problem is when I click the button for the first time, the Modal is empty (the state is not updated). But when I click for the second time, everything is good (the state is updated).

Comment: Well it's probably not related to the first or second click but the async operation you are performing on button click, but again it's hard to pinpoint the issue without being able produce it.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Yes asynchronous, I thought so too, here if you wanna see the file [link](https://codepen.io/ervanrahadian/pen/ZELjzdw?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleUpdateTeams` function calls `dispatch` which causes the `myTeam` variable from `useSelector` to update, but your `.then()` callback is a closure created with the old value of `myTeam`.  So you are setting your component states based on the old Redux state rather than the new state.

You need to either:

- Get the new `data` value from the return value of the `dispatch`.
- Respond to changes in `myTeam.userData` *after* they occur by using a `useEffect` hook with `myTeam.userData` as a dependency.

As a sidenote, having 26 individual states is crazy.  I think you could use some objects here.

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah I need do something like `[state, setState] = useState({...});` to minimize the individual states

Comment: I follow all your steps, and it works. I need to set `myTeam.userData` as a dependency, thousand thanks.